# Disqus showing same comments on all pages with unique page.url and page.id set

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, disqus

I'm adding disqus to my django application and can not get it to load a new thread of comments on each page.

I have tried everything and followed the documentation, which states to set the variables in disqus javascript template before using.

Here is my 'post_detail.html' that needs disqus comments:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="post-entry">
    <h2>{{ post.title  }}</h2>
    <p>{{ post.body|safe }}</p>
  </div>
  <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
  <script>

  /**
  *  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
  *  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables*/

  var disqus_config = function () {
  this.page.url = '{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}';  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
  this.page.identifier = '{{ request.get_full_path }}'; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
  this.page.title = '{{ post.title }}'
  };

  (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
  var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
  s.src = 'https://bytewise-com.disqus.com/embed.js';
  s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
  (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
  })();
  </script>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
{% endblock content %}
```

The variables in this function are set correctly, per https://help.disqus.com/developer/javascript-configuration-variables

```
...
this.page.url = '{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}';
this.page.identifier = '{{ request.get_full_path }}';
...
```

Here is what my browser gets in response to loading the page, so I know the variables are loading correctly.

```
 /**
  *  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
  *  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables*/

  var disqus_config = function () {
  this.page.url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/1/';  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
  this.page.identifier = '/post/1/'; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
  this.page.title = 'Testing the post function'
  };

  (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
  var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
  s.src = 'https://bytewise-com.disqus.com/embed.js';
  s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
  (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
  })();
```

I have tried changing the variables manually too, to make sure they are entirely unique. Also tried using the django-disqus package and its template tags, with no results.

Why do the same comments still show up on my other posts?

Does it have anything to do with each post referencing the 'post_detail.html' template?

Been working on this for hours, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I viewed disqus admin page and it showed http://127.0.0.1:8000/post as the thread url, editing it gave me an error about invalid url format.
Seemed odd to me, so I deleted the site and the comments.

changing the variable to:

```
this.page.url = '{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}.html'
```

for whatever reason disqus seems to agree with this more, not sure if this is intended, but it seems to be working fine now.